# Angular not able to retrieve list of heroes in Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am trying to build up the Tour of Heroes Application from The Angular Docs.
After Defining my Array of Heroes and trying to loop through it, it only brings up empty divs.

this is my code below:

**html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelectHero(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>{{hero.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<div> 
    <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**typescript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './shared/model/hero';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title:string;
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;
  constructor(){
    this.title = 'app';
    this.heroes = HEROES;
  }
  onSelectHero(hero: Hero){
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "NightOwl",
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "Batman",
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "Superman",
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: "Spiderman",
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    name: "Hulk",
  }
];
```

Why is this is happening?

Comment: do you see the title

Comment: no,title just empty divs

Comment: check if you have any errors in console

Comment: ok, i get this AppComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
....

Comment: try  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelectHero(hero)">
      <span class="badge">{{hero?.id}}</span>{{hero.name}}
    </li>

Comment: ok, same thing..i just found out that clicking on any of the empty divs brings back all the text in the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your component code and comment below your question:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

**Option1:** you need to initialize `selectedHero` at your component

```
selectedHero: Hero = new Hero();
```

**Option2:** use safe navigator `?`

```
<div> 
  <h2>{{selectedHero?.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero?.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero?.name" placeholder="name"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Option3:** use `ngIf` to avoid accessing `selectedHero` while it's not been initiailized

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero"> 
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Comment:** The difference between Option1,2 and Option3 is that there'll be nothing about `selectedHero` been displayed while `selectedHero` is not been initialized at Option3.

Comment: Working fine now, used the ngIf directive!

Comment: @OLayemiGarubaDonyemisco glad to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not printing **div** elements but **il** elements (clickable). You have to click on one of the **il** elements to present the "Selected Hero" in the div of your html template.

If you want to show directly the list of heroes in **div** elements, you have to replace your template with:

```
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes"> 
   <h2>{{hero.name}}</h2>
   <div><label>id: </label>{{hero .id}}</div>
   <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
   </div>
  </div>
```